# Google Chrome not reading background-image

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a simple website, it works with Firefox, but with Chrome, all the background images don't show up. This is the the tag:

```
<header style="background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bootstrapvitality/assets/img/artmakeit/home.jpg'">
```

You can visit the website and see the difference between Firefox and Chrome [here](https://floating-scrubland-33453.herokuapp.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing `)` on the `url(...)`.

Comment: Ok sorry for the Typo ... looks like Firefox didn't care about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `)` at the end of the `background-image: url()` property.

The fact that it works in Firefox is just a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The image is just really really big. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPLGgb So you are probably only seeing the top left portion (which is all white). In the above code pen I made the header `width: 1200px;height: 1200px` and you see the image.